# Add text to an input field x when user clicks button x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of text inputs, each with an associated button.  Here's my setup: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geMtZ/549/)

I can get it working individually (see the top button which is working),

But how can I make it so clicking any of the buttons will change the text of its associated input (`button# --> text#`), without repeating the code for each item?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="text2" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button2" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="text3" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button3" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="text4" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button4" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="text5" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button5" /><br/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text1');
        text.val('Stuff');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bind event on all the buttons using the attribute selector. `$('[id^=button]')` will select all the elements whose id starts with `button`
2. Use `$(this)` inside the event handler to access the element that was clicked.
3. Use `prev`, will select the previous sibling of the element.
4. I recommend to add same class to all the buttons, so that event can be bound using the class. `$('.myButtons').on('click', function() {});`, and then you no longer need `id` on each of the button. This is also useful to style all the elements.

```js
$('[id^=button]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().val('Stuff');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text2" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text3" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button3" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text4" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button4" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text5" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button5" />
<br/>
```

---

The above code will not work if you change the HTML structure. You can use more flexible approach as below

1. Use `data-*` custom attributes to store the association of the button with the textbox.
2. When the button is clicked get the value of the `data-target` attribute and update the value of the corresponding textbox.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).val('Stuff');
});
```

```css
.text {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.button {
    border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" class="text" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="button" data-target="#text1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text2" class="text" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="button" data-target="#text2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text3" class="text" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="button" data-target="#text3" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text4" class="text" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="button" data-target="#text4" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text5" class="text" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="button" data-target="#text5" />
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use and **[attribute  start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** and **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[id^=button]').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).prev();
    text.val('Stuff');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text2" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text3" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button3" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text4" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button4" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text5" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button5" />
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('input:button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $(this).prev();
        text.val('Stuff');    
    });
});
```

Use input:button as selector and use .prev()

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/geMtZ/550/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Jsfiddle:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/geMtZ/551/)

The code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function () {

        console.log(1)

        var this_id = $(this)[0].id.split('button')[1];
        console.log(this_id)
        $('#text' + this_id).val('Stuff');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For buttons use class atribute. like

```
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 150px;" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" clas="btn"/>
```

Then use .btn as selector . on clicking this get its previous sibling which is input type="text" . Instead of class you can use same name for all buttons also.

**Javascript;**

```
$(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        var text = $(this).prev();
        text.val('Stuff');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a vanilla Javascript version:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=button]'), function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      this.previousElementSibling.value = 'Stuff';
    });
  });
});
```

Explaining the code:

1. When all the elements of the pages are already loaded / ready for use
2. We loop through all the `input` fields which `id` starts with `button`
3. For each of those elements, we add a `click` event handler
4. When the event is triggered, we look for the `previousElementSibling` of the button clicked
5. And then, we change its value to `'Stuff'`, as your example says.

Comment: Why did you go with VanillaJS, when OP is using jQuery

Comment: @Tushar for future reference. Anyone who comes from external links might want a pure JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting `input type="text"` having `id` where last character corresponds to clicked `input type="button"` element `id` last character

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
  $("input[type=text][id$=" + this.id.slice(-1) + "]").val(this.id /* "Stuff" */)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text2" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text3" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button3" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text4" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button4" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text5" style="width: 150px;" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button5" />
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can select all buttons like this `$( ":button" )` to avoid calling each button individually.

then you can get the textbox using `.prev()`

so your code should be like this

```
$(function () {
    $( ":button" ).on("click",function(){
        var $txt= $(this).prev();
        $txt.val("Hello World");
    });
});
```

You may test that at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/kaa5h35p/)